# Deleting Item from Dropdown in Flutter results in error

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I implemented a DropDown which contains a list of items you can delete.

**The Dropdown can't be displayed correctly after deleting the item and that causes the error but i don't know how to fix this. Help is highly appriciated!**

The DropDown:

[image]

The items are a collection of documents queried from firebase.

Deleting the item removes it from firebase but i get the following error:

[image]

This is my code:

```
var selectedStand;

  void deleteStand() {
    DocumentReference ref = Firestore.instance
        .collection('Standnamen')
        .document(selectedStand);
    ref.delete();
  }


          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Standnamen').snapshots(),
            // ignore: missing_return
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                Text("Loading");
              } else {
                List<DropdownMenuItem> standItems = [];
                for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length; i++) {
                  DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.documents[i];
                  standItems.add(
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text(
                        snap.documentID,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                      ),
                      value: "${snap.documentID}",
                    )
                  );
                }
                return Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    DropdownButton(
                      items: standItems,
                      onChanged: (standValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedStand = standValue;
                        });
                      },
                      value: selectedStand,
                      isExpanded: false,
                      hint: new Text(
                        "Choose stand to delete",
                  ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Detailed Error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#46c06):
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: example3. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 827 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> file:///Users/darjusch/Developer/flutterProjects/sommerobst_app_beta/lib/screens/admin/admin_create_stand_screen.dart:67:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      new DropdownButton (package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart:827:15)
#3      _AdminCreateStandScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:sommerobst_app_beta/screens/admin/admin_create_stand_screen.dart:92:23)
#4      StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:509:81)
#5      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:127:48)
#6      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4619:28)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
W/erobst_app_bet(20965): Reducing the number of considered missed Gc histogram windows from 119 to 100

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99569 pixels on the bottom.
```

EDIT:
I tried your suggestion which sounds very logical but it did not work i still get the same error.

```
var selectedDoc;
                      DropdownButton(
                        items: standItems,
                        onChanged: (standValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedStand = standValue;
                            selectedDoc = snapshot.data.documents.firstWhere(
                                  (doc) => doc.documentID == selectedStand,
                              orElse: () => null,
                            );
                          });
                        },
value: selectedDoc?.documentID,
```

Comment: Have you attempted to simply not show that widget when the List of options is empty with a condition?

Comment: You mean for the case that there is no item left because all are deleted?

Comment: There are multiple items in the list so this shouldnt be the problem but i can include that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After deletion `DropdownButton` is given a `value`(`selectedStand`) that none of the `DropdownMenuItem`s contain. So, first check if a document exists whose `id` is `selectedStand` otherwise set `value` to `null`.

```
// get the document with id as selectedStand. Will be null if it doesn't exist.
var selectedDoc = snapshot.data.documents.firstWhere(
  (doc) => doc.documentID == selectedStand,
  orElse: () => null,
);

DropdownButton(
  // assign selectedDoc's id (same as selectedStand) if exists
  // otherwise null
  value = selectedDoc?.documentID,
  // ...
),
```

The logic should not be in `onChanged` but outside of `DropdownButton` within the `StreamBuilder`.

```
selectedDoc = snapshot.data.documents.firstWhere(
  (doc) => doc.documentID == selectedStand,
  orElse: () => null,
);

return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    DropdownButton(
      items: standItems,
      onChanged: (standValue) {
         setState(() {
         selectedStand = standValue;
        });
      },
      value: selectedDoc?.documentID,
      isExpanded: false,
      hint: new Text(
        "Choose stand to delete"
      ),
   ),
  ],
),
```

Alternatively you could set `selectedStand = selectedDoc?.documentID` right after finding `selectedDoc`, so that `selectedStand` will always have a valid value.

Comment: This sounds like the solution to the problem but it did not work do you know why? I edited my post

Answer (score -1):

I guess the problem is that you are adding to the same variable without clearing it first which cause multiple element of items to be there with the same names. So I would suggest clear out the items in standItems right before you call the add function to add items outside the for loop.